# Transposing CSV of IP data (splitting a single row into many customer number - IP pairs)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Customer #1 | IP 1 | IP 2   
Customer #2 | IP 1 | IP 2 | IP 3 | IP 4 |
```

Which I need to get in the format of

```
Customer #1 | IP 1 | 
Customer #1 | IP 2 | 
Customer #2 | IP 1 | 
Customer #2 | IP 2 | 
Customer #2 | IP 3 | 
Customer #2 | IP 4 |
```

As in a single line per IP with customer numbers repeated for every line.

**The actual format of the CSV is like this for a single line**

220386|230.31.344.*,230.31.135.*,230.31.136.*,230.31.143.*,213.31.198.*,270.34.149.*,216.31.160.*,260.32.191.*|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

**The customer number is the first number followed by all the corresponding IPs in format "|x,y,z|"**

The difficulty is that the there are several thousand customer rows with each customer having hundreds to several thousand distinct IPs.

Would anyone have any ideas of the best way to do this?

Comment: Is that really your `csv`? If it's `|` separated like that, `pandas` is going to have an issue tokenizing that, or is there some delimiter you just haven't shown?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for doing so? Off the top of my head, read both into data frames. Iterate through rows & columns in data frame to make a new series of customers and one for IPs. Then combine into df, export to csv.

Comment: I agree, can you please edit the question with the original format of the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that starting `csv` here's what you need. The key is to `set_index()` to the field that's your customer ID then `stack`, after ensuring each field is split into a separate column, and that fields that don't exist for that customerID are filled with a `null` value (so that `stack` drops these when making it long)

```
df = (pd.read_csv('your_file', sep='\n', header=None)[0]   # Read in entire lines
        .str.split('\|', expand=True)               # pandas splits into separate fields
        .set_index(0).stack()                       # Transform from wide to long
        .reset_index(1, drop=True)                  # Remove unnecessary level
        .rename_axis(None)                          # Remove index name
        .str.strip()                                # Remove leading/trailing white space
        .loc[lambda x: x.ne('')]                    # Remove empty lines due to dangling |
     )
```

---

Output:

```
Customer #1     IP 1
Customer #1     IP 2
Customer #2     IP 1
Customer #2     IP 2
Customer #2     IP 3
Customer #2     IP 4
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend that your IP columns are named like this 'IP 1', 'IP 2' etc...

Then I believe you whant to do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
ip_list = ['IP 1', 'IP 2', 'IP 3', 'IP 4']

final_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Customer_ID'], value_vars=ip_list)
```

It will also create a column named `value` with the number of occurrence of each couple. If you do not want it just add 'final_df.drop(axis=1, columns=['value'], inplace=True)`